# floating point value not working if the value is not manually assigned

Tags: shell, if-statement, floating-point

I need to check if the percentage change is > 0, ==0, < 0, and NULL.
So I got get_count() that returns result of SELECT statement...:

```
get_count () {
    sqlplus -s un/pass <<!
    set heading off
    set feedback off
    set pages 0
    select trunc(PRNCT_CHANGE, 3) 
    FROM SEMANTIC.COUNT_STATISTICS;
   exit;
!
}

count=$(get_count $1) #possible values: -0.789, -10.999, 11.897, 20, 1, 0...

if [ -z "$count" ]; then
    echo "The count percentage change returns null value"
elif [[ "$count" -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "The count percentage change ($count) is greater than zero"
elif [[ "$count" == 0 ]]; then
    echo "The count percentage change stays unchanged (is zero)"
elif [[ "$count" =~ ^[\-0-9] ]]; then
    echo "The count percentage change is $count" 
else
   echo "$count  ... Something else is wrong here"
fi
```

If I manually assign value for `$count` ie:

```
count=-0.987
```

This is working great.

otherwise if I let get_count() method return the value, it is always jumping to `else` statement...

Should I convert the value that gets passed to `$count` variable somehow..?

Comment: Your `get_count` doesn't actually use the argument passed to it.

Comment: Yea...I get the value. Because it gets echoed out:  "-71.888  ... Something else is wrong here"

Comment: is that what you meant? @chepner

Comment: I'm just pointing out that your function will return the same value no matter what the value of `$1` is. That may be relevant after your immediate problem is fixed.

Comment: yes, i commented out the complexity of the query@chepner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` doesn't understand floating point values. You'll need to use an external program like `bc` to do the comparison:

```
if [ -z "$count" ]; then
    echo "The count percentage change returns null value"
elif [[ $(echo "$count > 0" | bc ) -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "The count percentage change ($count) is greater than zero"
elif [[ $(echo "$count < 0" | bc ) -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "The count percentage change ($count) is less than zero"
elif [[ "$count" == 0 ]]; then
    echo "The count percentage change stays unchanged (is zero)"
else
   echo "$count  ... Something else is wrong here"
fi
```